# Does Hawking radiation depend of what's inside a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Or is it entirely based on the existence of an event horizon?

Does the fact that black holes radiate depend on any properties of its interior?

Comment: *properties of its interior* The interior is *vacuum*.

Comment: I think Ghoster got it 100% right. The curious thing about fundamental physics is that we seem to be dealing with the properties of nothing.

Comment: @Ghoster In every black hole there is an star... so no vacuum...

Comment: That’s not true.

Comment: [Why is the Schwarzschild black hole a vacuum solution?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320196/why-is-the-schwarzschild-black-hole-a-vacuum-solution)

Answer (score 0):

No, it just depends on the volume and mass of the sphere. This is all theoretical however.

Excerpt from wikipedia

> The radiation temperature is inversely proportional to the black hole's mass, so micro black holes are predicted to be larger emitters of radiation than larger black holes and should dissipate faster per their mass.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I need to emphasize upfront that the radiation is not coming from the interior or the matter that formed the black hole. It's coming from the horizon distorting nearby quantum fields.

Your question is intimately related to the information paradox. Let's consider a neutral, non-rotating black hole. Regardless of the particular matter and radiation that collapsed to form the black hole, the horizon will emit a thermal spectrum of radiation at temperature:
$$ T= \frac{\hbar c^3}{ 8 \pi k G M }$$

This is what happens no matter the initial conditions which settled to form the neutral, non rotating black hole.

Taken to the extreme, this is in tension with quantum mechanics. Consider a basic particle scattering experiment. N particles go in, M particles come out. While the outcome of the experiment is not determined by quantum mechanics, the results follow certain probabilistic patterns, correlations, and rules. Furthermore, if you don't know the identity of the N incoming particles, you can deduce from the M outgoing particles the probability for what the original N incoming particles were. Information is not lost.

Black holes seemingly mess with this. In that case an enormous number of particles go in, ~10^60 for a solar mass black hole. These ~10^60 particle form an event horizon which then radiates at a thermal spectrum of M photons until the black hole disappears.

The matter which formed the black hole contained an enormous amount of info. Where did it go? Was it transferred out through the radiation? That's hard to justify because thermal radiation contains almost no information. It's very high entropy. Imagine trying to send a copy of the entire 30+ years of the internet through a radio signal of pure static. Sounds impossible right? Copying the info in a black hole through thermal radiation is much, much more difficult, exponentially so.

You may counter that normal quantum systems emit thermal radiation all the time. Heat up a piece of metal and it'll thermally radiate. Yes, but the metal doesn't disappear behind a shrinking event horizon. So it's theoretically possible to reconstruct the insanely complicated quantum interactions that caused the red hot metal to emit radiation.

Now consider the contrast.

1)In quantum mechanics, N particles scatter and produce M particles. The M outgoing particles are probabilistically correlated to the N incoming particles.

2)With general relativity, N particles form a black hole which thermally radiates away as M photons. The thermal radiation doesn't seem to contain any information about the original N particles.

What's going on? Where is the information about what formed the black hole? Good question. I don't know.

Comment: Particle number is not conserved, not even in low energy processes. Consider the "scattering" of an optical photon on a piece of dark paper. A 2eV photon "goes in" and a bunch of infrared photons with 0.2eV (and much lower) "come out". This phenomenon has absolutely nothing to do with black holes. The first physical question one could ask are if electric charge and lepton number are conserved. Theorists seem to prefer the scenario that conserves charge but not lepton number. As an experimentalist I would like to see that demonstrated in an experiment, if only on a microscopic black hole.

Comment: Actually, I have to modify that further. The first question one could ask is if energy is conserved locally. In case of a wormhole it would not be. The cosmological solution is also not energy conserving in the local sense. One can therefor ask seriously if it is conserved in black holes. They may "shrink" faster or slower than predicted by the theory without making up for that with a difference in Hawking radiation flux. There are plenty of unknowns here... and the theory can't answer any of them.

Comment: @FlatterMann, I never said particle number was conserved.  But the outgoing energy and momentum of any scattering process is conversed and correlated with what follows, even if a trillion photons disappear.

Comment: That energy and momentum are conserved are assumptions of the theory. Nobody has ever measured that on an actual black hole. The point is that the usual explanation of black hole thermodynamics differs in nothing from the analysis of that of a body with very high thermal mass as far as I can tell. There is no there there. The really interesting questions (like lepton number conservation) can simply not be addressed. We do not know anything about quantum gravity.

Comment: @Flatterman, einstein equations by construction conserve local energy-momentum.  $∇_{a}T^{a,b}=0$ Every bit of energy and momentum in a smooth local region is accounted for.  It's the global conservation that causes problems when one considers the cosmological solutions. and those pesky singularities ;)

Comment: Einstein's equations have not been verified on black holes. I am not trying to kick off an argument here, but there is a difference between theory that has been confirmed by experiment and extrapolation of theory that has not been. I am conservative, so I don't think we would see much of a surprise with regards to energy and momentum conservation (unless wormholes actually exist). Like I said, the big question is whether black holes are lepton recyclers for the next era of the universe or not. Theory can not answer that.

Comment: @Flatterman, "The point is that the usual explanation of black hole thermodynamics differs in nothing from the analysis of that of a body with very high thermal mass as far as I can tell. There is no there there. " Experts agree with you :) It's called the "central dgoma" among the experts on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151080/discussion-between-flattermann-and-michael-c).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @safesphere, the question is about whether the interior determines the properties of the radiation. One popular resolution to the info paradox is that the interior of the BH is somehow encoded in the radiation. If the radiation somehow encodes info about the interior, then yes, the interior determines the properties of the radiation. That was one of the questions, so yes, my answer is relavent.

Comment: @safesphere, "The interior is in the future relative to the entire external universe." Is the interior in the future relative to the volume of space that will exist after the black hole evaporates?

Comment: @safesphere, this is a common misunderstanding due to only studying geodesics of test particles that don't backreact on the metric. Consider a growing BH made from 2 separated, equal mass concentric shells, P & Q.  P collapses 1st and asymptotes to a BH with radius SR(P), then Q collapses and asymptotes to a larger BH with radius SR(Q+P). Now, SR(P) < SR(Q+P), so shell P is inside SR(Q+P). Are there 2 horizons SR(P) and SR(Q+P)? That would violate Birkhoff's theorem. Therefore SR(P) became SR(Q+P). Event horizons are dynamic, they can grow. That's how BH form in finite time.

Comment: @safesphere, now since event horizons can form and grow in finite time, as my last comment indicates, basic QFT in the region of the horizon implies Hawking radiation. If the horizon doesn't shrink the Hawking radiation will never stop, making the radiating horizon a source of infinite energy. But luckily, the radiation will cause the horizon to shrink, so that disaster is avoided.

Comment: @safesphere what? 1)Your 1st point is physically absurd as it would imply the asymptotic EH of an in-falling shell would push anything in the center outwards as the EH grows. Whether you're talking about something physical or just an artifact of coordinates, neither happens. 2) Your 2nd point is mathematically wrong. Integrations over lengths, areas, and volumes inside the horizon are finite. Check the metric and the 3D integration measure. If the signature switch confuses you, just switch to Gullstrand-Painleve coordinates which can cross the EH easy and the spatial geometry is Euclidean.

Comment: Your source contradicts you:"The 3-dimensional spatial volume inside a black hole [...] depends explicitly on the definition of time, and can even be time dependent, or zero." If it can be 0 then it can be non-0, and indeed they show multiple coordinate systems in which it isn't 0. 3D volume isn't covariant. In Sch. coordinates it's 0 because r can't extend beyond the EH. So just use different coordinates that can. All of your statements about the EH and volumes come from using Sch coordinates beyond their usefulness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151173/discussion-between-michael-c-and-safesphere).